# partial form HTML is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) and trying to apply the material to a previous project I started in rails.

This is my `main.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('outpostApp').config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/posts.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).state('newPost', {
    url: '/submit',
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/post-add.html',
    controller: 'CreatePostController'
  });
}).run(function($state) {
    $state.go('main');
});
```

This is my `posts.html`:

```
<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
<a ui-sref="newPost" class="btn-primary btn-lg nodecoration">Add New Post</a>
```

this is my `post-add.html`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addPost()">
  <div ng-include src="'partials/_form.html'"></div>
</form>
```

I am using the same `_form.html` with some modifications:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just wondering why the form won't load after I click on the button to 'Add New Post'.  I get a big empty screen. My _form.html is located under client/app/partials/_form.html.  I am not sure if it something with the file path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the w3schools documentation, `ng-include` should receive the path to the file, instead of using the attribute `src`. So, instead of

`<div ng-include src="'partials/_form.html'"></div>`

You should do the same you dor for

`<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>`

Therefore

```
<div ng-include="'partials/_form.html'"></div>
```

I recommend you to always open your browser Network and verify if the file you need is being requested, this way you have a sense of what is happening in your application and its easier to fix the problem.

Ps. I am not sure about your paths, but by checking your console you should be able to verify whether or not the file is being requested and set it to the right location.

For more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and its still blank :(  I will have to keep trying.  This is kind of dumb but can you tell me how to use the console to check?  It isn't showing me any errors.

Comment: If you use Google Chrome, right click somewhere -> Inspect Element. On the tabs you will see Network, click on it and check all files that are being requested. I hope it helps.

Ps. If you work a lot with web development, I highly recommend you to explore the options the browser give your (Just a friendly advice :D)

Comment: makes more sense to look at angular docs that clearly show the `src` attribute. Don't trust w3schools as gospel ... it is wrong in a lot of places